# GraphQl array object inside object

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I do a json call from a api to get a list of posts. My problem is that inside of every post object response, i have a other array of object for the category of the post. How can get the array object category using Graphql?

i try this but return me error

```
const Cat = new ObjectType({
name: 'CatItem',
description: 'cat',
fields: () => ({


    id: {
        type: new NonNull(ID),
        description: 'cat',
        resolve: (root) => root.id
    },
    slug: {
        type: StringType,
        description: 'cat',
        resolve: (root) => root.slug
    },
    name: {
        type: StringType,
        description: 'cat',
        resolve: (root) => root.name
    },


}),
});

const PostType = new ObjectType({
name: 'PostItem',
description: 'post',
fields: () => ({
    id: {
        type: new NonNull(ID),
        description: 'post',
        resolve: (root) => root.id
    },
    slug: {
        type: StringType,
        description: 'post',
        resolve: (root) => root.slug
    },
    title: {
        type: StringType,
        description: 'post',
        resolve: (root) => root.title
    },
    content: {
        type: StringType,
        description: 'post',
        resolve: (root) => root.content
    },
    categories: {
        type: new List(CatType),
        description: 'post',
        resolve: (root) => root.category
    },
    date: {
        type: StringType,
        description: 'post',
        resolve: (root) => root.date
    },
    authorName: {
        type: StringType,
        description: 'post',
        resolve: (root) => root.display_name
    },
    authorAvatar: {
        type: StringType,
        description: 'post',
        resolve: (root) => root.user_avatar
    },
}),
});
```

Thank you

Comment: In general, if something is giving you an error, you should also post what the error is. It help others get an idea of what is wrong.

Comment: My error message is Field "categories" of type "[CatItem]" must have a sub selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that message because you have to tell GraphQL which fields (the subselection) within `categories` you want to retrieve.

You're probably trying to run a query something like this:

```
{
  post(id: 1) {
    title
    categories
  }
}
```

But you need to specify the fields to return (subselection) on `categories`, like the following:

```
{
  post(id: 1) {
    title
    categories {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Incidentally, there is a great tool called GraphiQL which is especially helpful when getting started writing queries. You might want to take a look at the middleware [express-graphql](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql).

Comment: I try to get all the posts but inside each post, i have a array object of each category like this.